# execvp ignore arguments with '

Tags: c, linux, execvp

I want to execute the following command

```
ubus -S call network.interface status '{"interface": "lan"}'
```

with `execvp` in C:

```
char* arg[] = {"ubus", "-S", "call", "network.interface" , "status", "'{\"interface\": \"lan\"}'", NULL};
execvp(arg[0],arg);
```

but the command does not work. I make an investigation and I found tha t the cause is the 5th argument (`'{"interface": "lan"}'`) contains a special charachter `'` which looks ignored by `execvp`.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: "*execvp ignore arguments with '*"

It won't. Try replacing `ubus` by `echo`.

Comment: Also `arg` misses the trailing `NULL` sentinel. It should be `char * arg[] = {..., NULL};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong path .. the argument reads `{"interface": "lan"}`, **not** `'{"interface": "lan"}'`. The quotes are just for your shell, so it knows the whitespace inside belongs to the argument instead of being the delimeter between two arguments. `ubus` will never see them.

*edit:* better say `ubus` *should* never see them, because in your implementation, it does, and that's just incorrect syntax to `ubus`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown your code, but an equivalent `execvp` call would look something like this:

```
char *args[] = {
    "ubus", "-S", "call", "network.interface", "status", "{\"interface\": \"lan\"}", NULL
};
execvp("ubus", args);
```